# Python post request display message if response taking longer than x seconds

Tags: python

I have the following python code that fetches data from a remote json file. The processing of the remote json file can sometimes be quick or sometimes take a little while. So I put the please wait print message before the post request. This works fine. However, I find that for the requests that are quick, the please wait is pointless. Is there a way I can display the please wait message if request is taking longer than x seconds?

```
try:
    print("Please wait")
    r = requests.post(url = "http://localhost/test.php")
    r_data = r.json()
```

Comment: you can't know how long it will take. And you can't print when post is running. You would have to run it in separated threads and it could be complex task. I wouldn't bother this and I would always display `"Please wait"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using multiple threads as follows:

```
import threading
from urllib import request
from asyncio import sleep


def th():
    sleep(2) # if download takes more than 2 seconds
    if not isDone:
        print("Please wait...")


dl_thread = threading.Thread(target=th) # create new thread that executes function th when the thread is started
dl_thread.start() # start the thread

isDone = False # variable to track the request status
r = request.post(url="http://localhost/test.php")
isDone = True

r_data = r.json()
```